# rspec undefined method `mobile_device?' for #<#<Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rspec

I'm trying to add a new class to a section of my header template if the app is being viewed on a mobile device and I'm getting this error from rake (but it works perfectly on localhost):

Failure/Error: render :template => "/layouts/_header.html.erb"
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `mobile_device?' for #<#:0x007fbbddbd0b50>

This is the line causing the problem in my header template:

**./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<div class="<%= 'flexslider-mobile' if mobile_device? && !current_page?('/') %>">
  <some html>
</div>
```

And this is the line I'm getting stuck on rendering the template in my test:

**./spec/views/layouts/application_spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'header' do

  before(:each) do
    render :template => "/layouts/_header.html.erb"
  end
```

**./app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   protected

def mobile_device?
    if session[:mobile_param]
      session[:mobile_param] == "1"
    else
      request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
    end
  end
  helper_method :mobile_device?
end
```

I'm new to rails and to rspec, so I'm sure it's something obvious, I just have no clue...Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you try method mobile_device? putting out of protected ?

Comment: Tried moving it out of protected, which doesn't make a difference. Not sure what you mean by "method mobile_device?"  Can you explain?  Thanks

Comment: i just meant moving mobile_device? out of protected ..thats it

Comment: Ah bummer. Yeah, doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out view tests don't have controller context, so I needed to stub the method before rendering:

```
  before(:each) do
    view.stub("mobile_device?" => false)
    render :template => "/layouts/_header.html.erb"   
  end
```

Works great. Thanks to danpickett for his assistance outside stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

The helper_method invocation must be declared above the protected keyword.

Comment: I've tried that, but still get the failing tests, sadly.